# 'default' as a variable name

Tags: c++, keyword, names

While debugging some code, I came across an array named `default`. I thought that keywords were not allowed as variable names.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int default = 5;
 printf("%d\n", default);
 return 0;
}
```

Now the above code compiles without a hitch on VS 2008. Isn't 'default' a keyword? How come it works as a variable name? Side-effects?

**PS:** `Infragistics::Win::UltraWinToolbars::ToolbarsCollection` has a property with this name!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=382138) in VC++. Basically by-design for C++/CLI compatibility.

Comment: Your link has expired and, unfortunately, I can't find a suitable replacement for it.