# Is this a valid C++ function or not?

Tags: c++

It seems to me that this function would not be valid since it uses the keyword 'default' as an identifier:

```
int foo()
{
    int default = 42;
    return default;
}
```

However, the Microsoft C++ compiler (versions 14.00.50727.762 and 15.00.30729.0) compile the code without warnings or errors (using the simplest possible command line: 'cl foo.cpp').

Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 does generate errors when compiling the function.

This seems like such an obvious problem that I must be overlooking something.

**Edit:** [litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/litb) dug up the **Duplicate** for this question [Default as a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664123/default-as-a-variable-name/664134#664134).

Comment: It's a known bug in microsoft's c++ compiler. There's another question wondering about that, but i'm not currently able to find it.

Comment: It's funny. Once happend to me with the 'auto' keyword (spanish for car)

Comment: Now that's what I call a bug! It must be really hard to write a parser that can't recognise reserved words!

Comment: MS C++ 13.10.4035 returns an error, I can't imagine why 14 and 15 don't.

Comment: This seems like an interesting error condition, and worthy of note.

Comment: duplicate is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664123/default-as-a-variable-name

Answer (score 2):

MS Visual C++ 6.0 and g++ 4.4.0 produce numerous errors - as they should. I find it hard to believe 
that a C++ compiler would accept this - are you sure you really compiled this code?

Answer (score 1):

default is a [reserved word](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/start), gcc 4.3.2 won't compile that code, not sure what the MS compiler is playing at there!

Answer (score 0):

No, default is a reserved c++ keyword, that's why its failing to compile.

Comment: he is saying that it compiled in MS compiler