# Is 'default' a context specific keyword in MSVC 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14, language-lawyer

Why does following code compiles successfully on MSVC 2015 (Update 3), and also on [VC++ Compiler online](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/)?

```
int main()
{
    int default = 10;
    cout << default*2; 
}
```

I don't see `default` should a context specific keyword. Then why VC++ is allowing it to be used as an identifier?

It fails on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/pXPYwN), however

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664123/default-as-a-variable-name) may still be the issue.  Looks like the link in the answer is broken